Unit Test Durable Functions -Isolated Proc
I am trying to add unit test for my Durable Orchestrator that is trigger by HTTP Trigger Function, I am using xUnit & Moq framework for testing. I have also found this
This is my code that I am trying to unit test:
 [Function(nameof(ESLDailyImportOrchestrator))]
    public async Task<string> ESLDailyImportOrchestrator(
        [OrchestrationTrigger] TaskOrchestrationContext context)
    {
        
            List<VusionItemRequestModel> currentBatch = await context.CallActivityAsync<List<VusionItemRequestModel>>(nameof(ImportItemsActivity), 50);

            string vusionCorrelationId = await context.CallActivityAsync<string>(nameof(ProcessDailyESLImport), currentBatch);

            return $"Processed batches with these CorrelationIds {vusionCorrelationId}.";
    }

I have found this documentation for unit testing Durable Function, but the document is not for Isolated Proc.
Can someone point me to right direction regarding this.
